# How to detect if user scrolled to bottom of specific div?

Tags: jquery

So I need to detect if a user has scrolled to the bottom of `.compare-wrapper` div , if he has then add `display:none`. Any suggestion on how to do that? I found a solution, but when div have scroll..I don't need that.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
            if($(this).scrollTop()>=$('.compare-wrapper').offset().top){
                $('.compare-menu-fixed').css('display','block');

            }
    });
```

Comment: you need to test the scrolling of the div, not the document. if a div has overflow and shows a scrollbar, it has its own scroll status, which doesn't apply to the document.

Comment: You need to consider `scrollTop` along with the height of the `div`

Comment: how to set condition for that?

Comment: @MarcB i dont need scroll in div only on whole page but i want to detect when its on bottom of div .

Comment: exactly. consider a scrollable div that's contained ENTIRELY within the viewable space of the page. the browser window has no scroll bar, therefore checking document scrolling is pointless: it'll always be both top+bottom because there's no scrollbar. the div, on the other hand, DOES have a scrollbar, and that can be at any position within the scrollable data. that's why you have to check the div's own scroll position. checkin on document only tells you where the main page has scroll to, which is whwer the div is, but tells you NOTHING about the div's own scrolling.

Comment: im not sure that i undestand u :S can i do that without adding scroll to div?